# Rails/Heroku - font incorrect yet included in fingerprinted assets and not overridden, works fine in dev

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, heroku, fonts

In my css:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Montserrat Reg';
src: asset-url('montserrat-reg.eot');
src: asset-url('montserrat-reg.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     asset-url('montserrat-reg.woff2') format('woff2'),
     asset-url('montserrat-reg.woff') format('woff'),
     asset-url('montserrat-reg.ttf') format('truetype'),
     asset-url('montserrat-reg.svg#montserratregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
font-family: 'Montserrat Bold';
src: asset-url('montserrat-bold.eot');
src: asset-url('montserrat-bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     asset-url('montserrat-bold.woff2') format('woff2'),
     asset-url('montserrat-bold.woff') format('woff'),
     asset-url('montserrat-bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
     asset-url('montserrat-bold.svg#montserratbold') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

This appears to compile properly in my fingerprinted assets but the page actually displays the default font despite the developer console in production showing:

```
body {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 font-family: 'Montserrat Reg'; }
```

The above shows exactly the same in development as well.  The sources tab  shows that the files referenced in the css are being included when I hit Ctrl + F5 in production, however, in development mode, the sources tab does not list the font files which indicates the fonts are coming from somewhere else.  This is the opposite of what I would expect. Any ideas what might prevent the browser from displaying properly?

Tested in Chrome and IE. For what it's worth I am also using font-awesome for the icons.

Rails 4.1.6 and 4.2.0

Comment: It may help to inspect element in your browser, then select one of the text elements that should have this font-family to see what CSS is or isn't acting upon it so that nothing else is overriding it.

Also this answer may help, make sure your path to the font files are correct:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605927/heroku-and-font-face-embedded-fonts-wont-display-on-heroku#4611375

Comment: The text elements both show the same content in the body{} noted above in the question which is what is really confusing.  The paths must be correct since they're being included and downloaded from the CDN when the font-family is added to the css.  Excluding font-family for the font causes them not to be downloaded from the CDN (which is expected).  I'm not sure how the paths could be incorrect yet still cause the fonts to be served.